# Whats the easiest way to know if a class is an ActiveRecord class?

Tags: ruby, class

So I know that I can do

```
 Class.new.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Base)
```

Is there a way to know what kind of class it is without instantiating it?  Are there any downsides to instantiating it just to find out the type of class it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Module#<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-3C):

```
SomeKlass < ActiveRecord::Base
=> true
```

Also, if you want to include `ActiveRecord::Base` itself to results, you can use `Module#<=`:

```
ActiveRecord::Base <= ActiveRecord::Base
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all ancestors of the Class with `Class.ancestors`. So what you can do to check the type without instantiating the Class is

```
Class.ancestors.include?(ActiveRecord::Base)
```